# Pattern matching in LDAP Distinguished Name Template

Tags: django, ldap, python-ldap

I am trying to authenticate users using django_auth_ldap. I have users in 2 different groups (say= Theta & Gamma, Alpha & Rho),

Currently, to search users I have created 2 authentication backends & mapped **USER_DN_TEMPLATE** like this:

```
'CN=%(user)s,OU=Television,OU=Theta,OU=Gamma,DC=example,DC=com'
```

to first backend & like  this :

```
'CN=%(user)s,OU=Television,OU=Alpha,OU=Rho,DC=example,DC=com'
```

to the second backend.

All my other settings are same. I know, this is not ideal setup but I want to know **what should my DN_TEMPLATE look like if I need to find all users in one authentication backend only?**

There should be some REGEX like pattern to replace Theta/Gamma/Alpha/Rho & then it should work (similar to `%(user)s` in above patterns.

The other approach will be to set some SCOPE_SUBTREE (& other variables) so that, it searches all users in `'DC=example,DC=com'`. I need help on those variables & values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave `AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE` unset, and set `AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH` instead.

> The [search/bind](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#search-bind) authentication method involves connecting to the
> LDAP server either anonymously or with a fixed account and searching
> for the distinguished name of the authenticating user. Then we can
> attempt to bind again with the user’s password.

For example, you can set the base search to a relative dn that is common to all users :

```py
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    "DC=example,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(CN=%(user)s)"
)
```

Or you can narrow the search by using multiple bases (search unions) :

```py
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearchUnion(
    LDAPSearch("OU=Television,OU=Theta,OU=Gamma,DC=example,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(CN=%(user)s)"),
    LDAPSearch("OU=Television,OU=Alpha,OU=Rho,DC=example,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(CN=%(user)s)"),
)
```

If you set `AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE`, django_auth_ldap will skip the search phase and proceed to a [direct bind](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#direct-bind) by deriving the user’s DN from his username and attempt to bind as the user *directly*.

As the DN template only allows one placeholder for the username, you can use the direct bind method only if all users have their entries in the same container.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, except the ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE parameter.. default value is 2. @ericLavault - could you provide more info on usability of this parameter in this context please?

Comment: `SCOPE_*` constants are defined by the module _ldap_ itself (python-ldap, not django_auth_ldap), so you need to `import ldap` to set the search scope to `ldap.SCOPE_*`. These are actually aliases to [those constants](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/master/Lib/ldapurl.py) from _ldapurl_ (python-ldap), which you can use as well.